# Type Error - not 'str' bytes-like object is required - Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, byte, string-formatting

I'm trying to web scraping in python. I'm using python 3.6 and import necessary packages for this. But I encounter an Attribute Error of 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'. If there is no `format` method for bytes, how to do the formatting or "rewriting" of bytes

```
 f = open(b'{0}.jpg'.format(flim.title.encode('utf8').replace(':','')) , 'wb')
 f.write(requests.get(all_img[1]['src']).content)
 f.close()
```

I was also facing the following problem

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and get rid of it by using 'b' right before the format specifier.

**UPDATE 1**

I remove the 'b' prefix and also give 'w' mode only and now I get the following error: **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

**Error**

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7a0edc6fdfd0> in <module>()
----> 1 download_poster(get_list())

<ipython-input-6-49c729cbcc37> in download_poster(list_)
     30                 #       f.write(requests.get(all_img[1]['src']).content)
     31 
---> 32                 f = open('{0}.jpg'.format(flim.title.encode('utf-8').replace(':','')) , 'w')
     33                 f.write(requests.get(all_img[1]['src']).content)
     34                 f.close()

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I was wondering I might make a silly mistake. Excuse me for that. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 2**

I somehow able to fix this by changing some format. Using `f-strings`(formatted string literals)

```
with open(f'{flim.title}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(all_img[1]['src']).content)
```

Comment: An important part of questions is including a traceback. I think removing the `b` prefix moves the issue elsewhere but you're aggregating it into a single issue.

Comment: Semantically, formatting doesn't make sense for bytes. You want to format a *string*, then (if needed) encode that string as a series of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is quite trivial.

### Preface

Python supports multiple prefixes to the `'someString'`

- `r'something'` : This is a raw string generally used when you're using file paths for example `file_path = r'C:\MyProjects\Python\TestProject'. It tells the interpreter that this is a`raw string`and no escape sequences (e.g.`\n`) have a meaning here.
- `f'something'` : This is a `string interpolation` feature available in `python3.5+` allows you to have place holders in the string to set a value. for example,

---

```
my_variable = 5 
some_string = f'I have {my_variable} apples with me'
# prints I have 5 apples with me
```

- `b'something'` : This indicates `bytes` although you type in a string here, since a string is a sequence of `bytes`, the interpreter understands the prefix `b` as bytes.

### Your issue:

Since you have a `b'{0}.jpg'` python understands it as `bytes` and not a string. The `.format()` is a string function and not a `bytes` function and hence the error

> `Attribute Error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'`

**How to resolve it?**

Simple, you can simply remove the prefix `b` from the `b'{0}.jpg'` and it'll start to work.

**The second issue you've mentioned:**
Now about the second issue, you've opened the file in `wb` mode, that stands for `write bytes` because of which it's expecting `bytes` as an input to write.

**How to resolve it:**

Simply, open the file in `w` mode which would accept `strings`. I'll  add a sample in just a moment.

---

**Your updated code:**

```
f = open('{0}.jpg'.format(flim.title.replace(':','')) , 'w')
f.write(requests.get(all_img[1]['src']).content)
f.close()
```

Alternatively if you're using `python3.5+` I use string interpolation:

```
f = open(f'{flim.title.replace(':','')}.jpg', 'w')
f.write(requests.get(all_img[1]['src']).content)
f.close()
```

Also, a better way to do it would be using the `with` keyword to avoid any `Resource Leaks`

```
with open(f'{flim.title.replace(':','')}.jpg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(all_img[1]['src']).content)
```

You don't need to do a `f.close()` since the `with` statement would automatically close the file for you.

Comment: But the issue is pushed elsewhere. The OP, I think, assumes that both errors come entirely from `b'{0}.jpg'` but it's not the case. Removing the`b` prefix fixes the first issue.

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, see your updated code in my answer, there are two changes, one is the `b` and second is the `w` in `wb` when you're defining the mode in which the file is to be opened.

Comment: @iam.Carrot Thanks for your brief explanation. But unfortunately i still get similar problem. I remove 'b' prefix and also put 'w' in mode and now it shows 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' '. 

I have heard about string interpolation in Swift. While i'm using string interpolation here ( what you gave ) it gives syntax error. I'm sorry , i think i'm missing something here.

Comment: About the string interpolation, as i mentioned, you need to have python 3.5+ maybe you're using a lower version of python that doesn't support string interpolation

Comment: About the bytes error, I am not sure why is it still causing the error, can you please update your code after the changes. It'll help clarify a few things.

Comment: @iam.Carrot I update my code , please check it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. It makes more sense. One last thing. Can you add your stack trace to the question too?

Comment: @iPhoton did it start working?

Comment: @iam.Carrot yes , it is and thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

You have opened file in `wb` mode, Hence file requires `byte` not string.

You can do one of the following,

1. Open file in `w` mode.
2. Convert data to byte.

**Open file in `w` mode**:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open('my.txt', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write('123')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> with open('my.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('123')
...
3
>>>
```

**Convert data to byte:**

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open('my.txt', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write('123')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> with open('my.txt', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(b'123')
...
3
>>>
```